# Convert SWF files to PNG images on Linux

Tags: python, linux, flash

***Before someone posts a complain that there are similar questions already answered, please keep reading.***

I've been working on a bot that takes SWF files from the Club Penguin archives (e.g. [Houndstooth Bag (icon)](http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/v2/content/global/clothing/icons/3226.swf)) and renders that file to a PNG image. Currently, I've been using the  `swf`  module from Python to do this, but it sometimes [leads to unwanted results](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141105230356/clubpenguin/images/archive/e/e2/20141107004524%21Houndstooth_Bag.png), and other attempts (swfrender, swfextract, gnash, etc.) render the image as it looks on the webpage (like it's cut in half).

The question is: is there a way to do these conversions with a script, using any Linux program or Python library, in such a way that the output images look professional (something like the exported images from [JPEXS](http://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/) or any other decent SWF decompiler)?

My Python code looks more or less like this (I am aware that the output is a SVG, but the SVG-PNG conversion is fairly simple, so this hasn't been a concern at all).

```
from swf.movie import SWF
from swf.export import SVGExporter

file = open('item.swf', 'rb')

swf = SWF(file)

svg_exporter= SVGExporter()

svg = swf.export(svg_exporter)

open('item.svg', 'wb').write(svg.read())
```

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out that `swfbbox` and `swfcombine` did pretty much of the work. Thanks for the help, though.

For the future readers (myself included):

```
$ swfbbox -o newfile.swf file.swf -e
$ swfcombine -s 5000 -o newfile.swf --dummy newfile.swf
$ swfrender -o file.png newfile.swf
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look at [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/) .

Image extract example :

```
$ swfextract myfile.swf

Objects in file myfile.swf:
[-i] 3 Shapes: ID(s) 1-3
[-i] 5 MovieClips: ID(s) 4, 5, 8, 10, 12
[-j] 3 JPEGs: ID(s) 69, 116, 447
[-p] 1 PNG: ID(s) 318
[-s] 3 Sounds: ID(s) 28-30
[-f] 10 Frames: ID(s) 0-10

$ swfextract -p 318 myfile.swf -o out_file.png
```

Also there is a `swfrender` utility , which isn't finished yet,
and will only work for *very* simple SWF files. (No Actionscript, no
gradient fills, no morph shapes, no blending modes, no filters, etc.)

```
$ swfrender myfile.swf -X pixelsize -Y pixelsize -o out_file.png
```

You can check the [python bindings](http://www.swftools.org/gfx_tutorial.html) if you interested .

Comment: Did you try it with the file I linked?